# Free antivirus for windows 2003

Tags: windows, anti-virus, windows-server-2003

What are some effective free antivirus solutions available for Windows Server 2003? I tried AVG 10.0  but it gave me an error.

Comment: "it gave me error", without telling _what_ was the error, is just about the worst thing you can say in a site like this.

Comment: FYI most AntiVirus software does not run on server versions of windows. in particular real time scanners

Comment: AVG for Windows Server 2003 is not free. I suspect that you tried to install the free version of AVG on your server and that the error you got was related to the fact that AVG Free cannot be installed on that operating system.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty subjective, but you could try [ClamAV](http://www.clamwin.com/). It should run on Windows Server 2003. Other compatible antivirus programs are listed in [this TechNet thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrantivirusandantispam/thread/ebe65e2b-c6f7-4d1b-884c-04e36dfca985).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Comodo Internet Security](http://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/free-internet-security.php). It runs on my Windows Web Server 2008 R2 x64 and should run on Windows Server 2003 too.

It's free to both business and home users.